Angular, Each Component getting a new Instance of a Service
I'm injecting a service in 2 different components. And each time I move from one component to another, a new instance of the service get's created. Here is my service ReportService:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'; 

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 

export class ReportService { 

  private message = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Initial message!!!'); 
  getMessage = this.message.asObservable(); 
  constructor() { alert('creating an instance of ReportService') }   setMessage(message: string) { 
    this.message.next(message); 
  } 
} 


First component, this component is updating the message by calling updateMessage() onclick of a button:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Org } from '../../data/org'; 
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { ReportService } from '../../report.service'; 

@Component({ selector: 'app-org', templateUrl: './org.component.html', }) 

export class OrgComponent implements OnInit {
 org: Org = new Org(); 
message: string=""; 

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private reportService: ReportService) { } 

updateMessage(){ 
this.reportService.setMessage("New Message"); 
} 

ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.reportService.getMessage.subscribe(msg => this.message = msg); 
} 
}


Second Component:
import { Liquidity } from '../../data/liquidity'; 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'; import \* as Docxtemplater from 'docxtemplater'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { ReportService } from '../../report.service'; 

@Component({ selector: 'app-liquidity', templateUrl: './liquidity.component.html', styleUrls: \['./liquidity.component.css'\] }) 

export class LiquidityComponent implements OnInit { 
message: string=""; 
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private reportService: ReportService) {} 

ngOnInit() { 
this.reportService.getMessage.subscribe(msg =\> this.message = msg); 
}
} ```

**
I expect that the service to be singleton, so that I can use it to share the data between components. The second component should get the updated message, however, every time I land on the second component I get the default message = 'Initial message!!!' I believe this is because a new instance of ReportService is being created every time I move from one component to another.
**


Can you please format your code correctly, thank you.

If you use providedIn: 'root' your service should be a singleton. Did you add it to a providers property in some modules ?

I'm using providedIn: 'root' and I haven't added it to providers section App Module. I don't have any other modules.

@Yogi please share a stackblitz where the issue happens

@NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ydq82f?file=src%2Fapp%2Freport.service.ts

@Yogi you shared a blank stackblitz, make the changes, then give save, then click share button and share the URL here!
